# Spit array with strtok and store tokens in unique null terminated strings

Tags: c, strtok

I have a string array cmd with a capacity of 255 chars declared this way:

```
char cmd[255];
```

I used fgets to get user input this way:

```
fgets(cmd, 256, stdin);
```

I have three separate arrays to store three tokens (assuming user only enters a string with at most 2 white spaces) declared this way:

```
char arg[20];
char arg2[20];
char arg3[20];
```

I split the string in cmd with strtok this way:

```
char *p = strtok(cmd, " ");

while (p!= NULL) {

// I want to store the tokens p in the arrays here (e.g:
// arg = p is not working
// arg2 = p ...

p = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

Assigning the value in pointers this way is not working. Can i get some help on what to do?

I must store the tokens inside null terminated strings

Comment: spit->split.  C cannot spit!!! : )

Comment: NUL character is '\0', not NULL.  There is a big difference.

Comment: Correct wording is "NUL terminated string", not "null terminated ..."  NUL is a '\0' where NULL differs from platform to platform. It is usually (void *)0.

Comment: `fgets(cmd, 256, stdin);` off-by-one error --> `fgets(cmd, 255, stdin);` or `fgets(cmd, sizeof cmd, stdin);`, or `char cmd[255];` --> `char cmd[256];`

Comment: Use `sscanf` like `int ret_scnf = sscanf(cmd, "%19s %19s %19s", arg, arg2, arg3);`

Comment: @Nguaial If it said "`NULL` terminated string" you'd be correct. However "null terminated string" *is* correct because the character with ASCII code 0 is called the null character (also called NUL and also called `'\0'`).

Comment: @immibis - So are you saying NULL and null are different? Since NULL and NUL sound the same, it really confuses a lot of people, especially the beginners.  It confused me.  I would prefer the usage of the word 'character' following  NUL: NUL character. By saying NUL character, this will  differentiate between NUL character and NULL.

Comment: @Nguaial That's also correct. Yes NULL and null are different in C programming. This shouldn't surprise you any more than the fact that "0" and 0 are different (or 0 and zero). "null character" is unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARG_LEN 20

int main(void){
    char cmd[256];

    if(fgets(cmd, sizeof cmd, stdin)){
        char arg[ARG_LEN+1], arg2[ARG_LEN+1], arg3[ARG_LEN+1];
        char *args[] = { arg, arg2, arg3, NULL };
        char **pp = args;
        const char *delimiter = " \t\n";//Include \n

        for(char *p = strtok(cmd, delimiter); p && *pp; p = strtok(NULL, delimiter)){
            strncpy(*pp, p, ARG_LEN);
            (*pp++)[ARG_LEN] = 0;//Cut it if it is too long
        }
        for(size_t i = 0; args + i < pp; ++i){
            printf("argument #%zu: '%s'\n", i+1, args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

sscanf version.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Stringification
#define S_(n) #n
#define S(n) S_(n)

#define FMT "%" S(ARG_LEN) "s"

#define ARG_LEN 20

int main(void){
    char cmd[256];

    if(fgets(cmd, sizeof cmd, stdin)){
        char arg[ARG_LEN+1], arg2[ARG_LEN+1], arg3[ARG_LEN+1];
        char *args[] = { arg, arg2, arg3 };
        int ret_scnf = sscanf(cmd, FMT FMT FMT, arg, arg2, arg3);
        for(int i = 0; i < ret_scnf; ++i){
            printf("argument #%i: '%s'\n", i+1, args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the argument is too long, the behavior of the two codes will be different.

Comment: Great.  The fact that the code kept all the original variable names as specified.  I have a Question: Since post increment has higher priority than de-reference operator, isn't supposed to be (*pp)[ARG_LEN] = 0; pp++;  So you are cutting the current before you move to the next one.

Comment: Yes.  That proves that your code is correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The follow could be work.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char cmd[255] = "";
    char arg[20]  = "" ;
    char arg2[20] = "";
    char arg3[20] = "";
    char *p;

    fgets(cmd, 255, stdin );

    p = strtok(cmd, " ");
    if ( p != NULL ) {
        strcpy( arg, p );
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
        if ( p != NULL ) {
            strcpy( arg2, p );
            p = strtok(NULL, "");
            if ( p != NULL ) {
                strcpy( arg3, p );
            }
        }
    }


    printf(" arg=%s\n arg2=%s\n arg3=%s\n", arg, arg2, arg3);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:  Declare argv as below

```
 char argv[3][20];
```

By doing this, it will simplify the code like below:

```
int
main(void)
{
   char cmd[255];
   char argv[3][20];
   char *token;
   char *tstr = " ";

   fgets( cmd, sizeof cmd, stdin );

   token = strtok( cmd, tstr );
   int i = 0;

   while( token != NULL )
   {
        strcpy( argv[i], token);
        printf( "%s\n", argv[i] );
        token = strtok( NULL, tstr ); 
        i++;
   }

   return 0;
}
```